# How to compress a time series plot, after taking out specific month from a dataset in python?

Tags: python

I have a dataset of OLR from 1986-2013 (daily data), and I am interested in plotting a time series which should have only boreal winter months i.e. from November to April.

(i) I am able to sort out Nov-Apr months from my datasets by using -

```
OLRNA = OLR.sel(TIME = OLR.TIME.dt.month.isin([11,12,1,2,3,4]))
```

and this is working.

(ii) But the problem is that whenever I am plotting a time series then that series is not continuous i.e not joining Nov-Apr for each year (showing gaps for remaining months). I know that as I have selected only Nov-Apr months in my data so it's not showing. Then how to join or compress the time axis?

how to plot this time series properly?

Answer (score 0):

Instead, first mask the months you do not want to plot and then remove these masked rows by applying `dropna`

```
OLRNA = OLR.mask(OLR.Time.dt.month.isin([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
OLRNA = OLRNA.dropna()
```

Comment: I am getting attribute error by using this.                                                               AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'mask'

Comment: Please check if `OLR`  and `OLRNA` are `pandas.DataFrame` objects ...otherwise give me an example of 'OLR' DataFrame.

Comment: Sir, actually I have a netcdf file of NOAA OLR...I want to share that but not able to attach. Can u plz share ur mail? So that I can share that.

Comment: if you have `google share` or `onedrive` please share a link... thx

Comment: well I see a json file `Code.ipynb`, a file called `NOAA_OLR.nc` which I assume contains data and a .pdf. But where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this issue and getting a proper plot. So answering my own question.

After selecting specific month from the time series. Just plot the series without considering 'time' on x-axis means just plot yaxis variable and let the x-axis denotes the serial numbers. And then with the help of matplotlib, just set the xticks and xticklabels manually wherever u want.

Thank you. Especially Bruno Vermeulen sir for the cooperation.